Android Emulator plugin in Jenkins seems to be not able to run due to "java.io.IOException: sdkmanager --" error
At the moment, I am actively trying to find a solution for mobile testing in Jenkins using emulators available for free. I found very interesting solution "Android Emulator" plugin for Jenkins. As per plugin documentation it should be possible:

Creating a new Android emulator

Its configuration can be parameterized, including OS version, screen size, locale and hardware properties
Android SDK dependencies are automatically downloaded and installed



I was able a few articles on using the plugin. However, it seems like dependencies are not installed automatically or there is something else going wrong with the plugin in my case. Whatever settings I try I see only errors and no running emulator.
In the Jenkins pipeline configuration I've set the following flag "Run an Android emulator during build". Oher parameters are:
Build Tools: Android Build Tools 4.0
SDK Home location: Local to the executor
Android OS version: 14
Density: 420
Resolution: WVGA
Emulator Name: Pixel 6 API 34
SD Card Size: 512
Target ABI: x86_64

However, I can see the following error in the Jenkins console log:
First time build. Skipping changelog.
SDK Manager is reading installed components
FATAL: sdkmanager --sdk_root=C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.tools.AndroidSDKInstallation\Android_Build_Tools_4.0 --channel=0 --install "platforms;14" "system-images;14;default;x86_64" failed. exit code: 1.
java.io.IOException: sdkmanager --sdk_root=C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.tools.AndroidSDKInstallation\Android_Build_Tools_4.0 --channel=0 --install "platforms;14" "system-images;14;default;x86_64" failed. exit code: 1.
    at jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.sdk.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:113)
    at jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.sdk.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:85)
    at jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.EmulatorRunner.run(EmulatorRunner.java:119)
    at jenkins.plugin.android.emulator.AndroidEmulatorBuild.setUp(AndroidEmulatorBuild.java:164)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper.setUp(SimpleBuildWrapper.java:294)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:158)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1895)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE

If some one had experience with this plugin recently, your support is highly appreciated. Maybe you can share settings that worked for you.
Also, I expected that plugin can download dependencies due to this flag in the Jenkins settings, but not sure it actually does:

